# angular 6 how to update property if no option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a group of radio buttons used for multi-choice questions. I can get the value of the selected option with the method below:

```
option = {id: 0, selected: 0};

radioChangeHandler(event: any) {
  if(event.target.value != "") {
      this.option.selected = event.target.value;;
  }
}

<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let option of question.options;">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="optradio"
                [value]="option.id" (change)="radioChangeHandler($event)">
        {{option.name}}
    </label>
</div>
```

however, I've been looking for ways to change the value of 'option.selected' back to 0 after it has been updated if no option is selected. All the suggestions I've found so far are mostly for updating the property with selected value. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from https://plnkr.co/edit/euuOC2Ir6qMViSvcbsYA?p=preview
I have been able to work out a solution for my case.
I created an Option model like so:

```
export class Option {
    id: number;
    questionId: number;
    name: string;
    isAnswer: boolean;
    selected = false;

constructor(data: any) {
    data = data || {};
    this.id = data.id;
    this.questionId = data.question;
    this.name = data.name;
    this.isAnswer = data.correct;
}
```

}

Then add the following properties and functions to the component:

```
questionOption: Array<Option>;
optionIndex: number;

optionClicked() {
  this.questionOptions[this.optionIndex].selected = true;
}

getUserAnswer(){
  let answer = 0;
  this.questionOptions.forEach((x) => { if(x.selected) answer = x.id;});
  this.userAnswers.push(answer);
  this.optionIndex = null;
}
```

and then in the html I use ngModel and ngModelChange like so:

```
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let option of questionOptions; let i = index">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="optradio" [(ngModel)] = "optionIndex"
                [value]="i" (ngModelChange)="optionClicked();">
        {{option.name}}
    </label>
</div>
```

With this I am able to get the option id of the selected option and if no option is selected, '0' is returned.

Answer (score 0):

By using ngModel to the input field and set default value '0'. Here is the stackblitz code https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-trmg92

Comment: thanks. I've seen your code and have tried it but after selecting an option in the first question which assigns the id of that option to 'selectedOption' property then click next button. On the next question if I did not select an option and click next, 'selectedOption' keeps the id of the first option I selected, it doesn't change back to '0' to reflect no option selected.